# Set Div to take up remaining height in parent with a sibling that has floated children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I have three components, a `#parent`, and 2 of it's children `#top` and `#bottom`.

`#parent` is not of a fixed size.

`#top` has children that are floated, and does not have a fixed size (it's children can change size). To fix it's height because of floating children, it uses this:

```
#top:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   line-height: 0;
   height: 0;
}
```

I want `#bottom` to take up the remaining height in the parent, If I use `height:100%` like normal it makes it overflow the same size as `#top`'s height.

I have also seen people use `overflow:none;` but this makes some of my content in `#bottom` get cut off.

How can I make `#bottom` take up the remaining height in `#parent`?

**EDIT:** [I made a jFiddle to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/SKkAp/). Also, I need to support back to IE 7. I am open to using Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to support back to IE 7

Comment: We need actual code here to reproduce the problem (where's the markup?).  IE7 support will *really* limit (or potentially eliminate) your options

Comment: I'll make a jsFiddle for it

Comment: Why do you need to have `#bottom` in the first place? Since `#bottom` is going to fill `#parent`, can you just put `#bottom`'s children in `#parent` and do away with the extra container?

Comment: @SlightlyCuban I'm sure there are plenty of reasons why one would need another div here rather than just using the parent. This is an abstraction of the issue to make it easier to deal with I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you float the top element then use `height: 100%;` this should solve the issue:

```
#top{
    background-color: blue;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/SKkAp/1/

What this does is now `bottom` actually fills the full `parent` since `top` is floated. But the content of `bottom` is pushed out of the way of the floated `top` making it appear as if `bottom` is filling the remaining space, where it's really filling the whole `parent`. Hopefully you can make sense of that. Haha

Comment: I don't know why this works, but the jFiddle don't lie. Thanks!

Comment: I'll add a description for you :)